# SnakeYaml issue in scala

Tags: scala, yaml, snakeyaml

I'm trying to figure out how to use nested data types with snakeyaml. I'm not able to get the inner class to display properly

```html
class RawEdgeTypeSpec() {
  @BeanProperty var edge_type: Int = -1
  @BeanProperty var weighted: String = ""
}

class RawNodeTypeSpec {
  @BeanProperty var node_type: Int = -1
  @BeanProperty var edge_types: List[RawEdgeTypeSpec] = List()
}


    val spec3 = new RawEdgeTypeSpec()
    spec3.setEdge_type(2)
    spec3.setWeighted("true")
    val spec2 = new RawNodeTypeSpec()
    spec2.setNode_type(2)
    spec2.setEdge_types(List(spec3))

    val output = new Yaml().dump(spec2)
```

This prints

```html
edge_types: !!scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon {}
node_type: 2
```

edge_types is not recognized and serialized properly

Similarly I'm having trouble deserializing yaml

Comment: Would you mind adding your imports so people can actually try and run your code? (also your build.sbt for specific dependencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SnakeYAML is a Java lib that doesn't know Scala, so you'll need to use `java.util.List[RawEdgeTypeSpec]` for SnakeYAML to understand that this is a list.